# Cost of .orderBy("id").startAt(n).limit(1) in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

What is the cost of a query like this in Firestore?

```js
collection.orderBy("id").startAt(n).limit(1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're charged a document read for each document that is read on the server for you. Since the query only reads one document, you'll only be charged one document read.